# Исчезает Pushpin при перемещении по карте

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, map

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если отдалить карту то на ней появляются повторы объектов, моя задача дать пользователю возможность самому указать пин путем его перемещения и вот когда я перемещаю его на локацию которая уже рендериться дважды он появляется на другой. Я пытался ограничивать масштаб но пин всеравно в фиксированной точке исчезает. Код банальный

```
private void map_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  pin.Location = map.ViewportPointToLocation(e.GetPosition(map));
}

<maps:Map x:Name="map" MouseMove="map_MouseMove" ZoomLevel="2"  CredentialsProvider="jvDLIntAl5Z27Ie4CW2A~t2CBU6uuDJKZaJk36XEeRA~Akm_PtBLLvYMIqAbzLeYg5g563oSNxFVOsoZDMKEubBHqzIMSzPNiCFf0o21CFJk">
  <maps:MapLayer x:Name="mapLayer">
    <maps:Pushpin x:Name="pin"/>
  </maps:MapLayer>
</maps:Map>
```

[Здесь проект вместе с открытым кодом самого контрола карты](https://github.com/mikelangelo-code/bingmapwpf)

Comment: Есть воспроизводимый пример? Как-то это можно запустить?

Comment: @aepot добавил линк на репозиторий

Comment: Кажется дело в [этом](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709538(v=msdn.10)#remarks). _If the specified values of Latitude and Longitude are not within the range of valid values for these properties, they are converted to valid values. The range of valid values for Latitude is -90 to 90. The range of valid values for Longitude is -180 to 180._ То есть вот такое вот поведение контрола. Быть может стоит свою булавку рисовать, а не встроенную. Ну или копаться в поведении карты глубоко, чтобы понять, как это объехать.

Comment: Другой вариант - ограничить положение карты на экране так, чтобы этот меридиан нельзя было визуально пересечь.

Comment: @aepot, скорее матрицу нужно както ограничить и зациклить при движении, но пока не могу понять как